# How can I create my own TokenFilter in PyLucene inherited from PythonTokenFilter

Tags: java, python, solr, lucene, pylucene

everyone:

I'm developing my own Analyzer in PyLucene 4.9.0 and created a TokenFilter for CompoundTokenFilter in the analyzer as the DictionaryCompoundTokenFilter not performing very well.

DictionaryCompoundTokenFilter uses a brute algorithm, but I'd like to split compound words only when the subwords in the compound word are all in the dictionary, like "breastcancer" is split when "breast" and "cancer" are both in the given dictionary.

But when running the program, it show that "the attribute 'length' of 'CharTermAttribute' objects is not readable", and I cannot find what's wrong with it.
Thanks!

```
from __future__ import division
import lucene, math, itertools

from java.lang import CharSequence
from java.io import IOException
from java.util import LinkedList
from org.apache.pylucene.analysis import PythonTokenStream
from org.apache.lucene.analysis import TokenFilter
from org.apache.pylucene.analysis import PythonTokenFilter
from org.apache.lucene.analysis import TokenStream
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes import CharTermAttribute
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes import OffsetAttribute
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes import PositionIncrementAttribute
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.util import CharArraySet
from org.apache.lucene.util import AttributeSource
from org.apache.lucene.util import Version

class CompoundTokenFilter(PythonTokenFilter):

    def __init__(self,matchVersion,input,dictionary,DEFAULT_MIN_WORD_SIZE,DEFAULT_MIN_SUBWORD_SIZE,DEFAULT_MAX_SUBWORD_SIZE):
        super(CompoundTokenFilter,self).__init__(input)
        self.matchVersion=matchVersion
        self.dictionary=dictionary
        self.tokens=LinkedList()
        self.minWordSize=DEFAULT_MIN_WORD_SIZE
        self.minSubwordSize=DEFAULT_MIN_SUBWORD_SIZE
        self.maxSubwordSize=DEFAULT_MAX_SUBWORD_SIZE
        self.current=AttributeSource.State
        self.termAtt=input.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class_)
        self.offsetAtt=input.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class_)
        self.posIncAtt=input.addAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class_)
        self.input=input

    def decompose(self):
        l=self.termAtt.length()
        s=self.termAtt.subSequence(0,l)
        if s in self.dictionary:
            self.tokens.add(CompoundToken(self.matchVersion,self.input,self.dictionary,self.minWordSize,self.minSubwordSize,self.maxSubwordSize,0,l))
        else:

            d=filter(lambda x:len(x)>=self.minSubwordSize and len(x)<=self.maxSubwordSize in s,this.dictionary)
            if len(d)>0:
                start=int(math.floor(l/self.maxSubwordSize))
                end=int(math.ceil(l/self.minSubwordSize))
                subwords_combinations=[]
                for i in xrange(start,end+1):
                    subwords_combinations.extend(itertools.permutations(d,i))
                subwords_combinations=filter(lambda x:''.join(x)==s,subwords_combinations)
                subwords=sorted(set(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,subwords_combinations)),key=lambda x:-1*len(x))
                for subword in subwords:
                    tokens.add(CompoundToken(self.matchVersion,self.input,self.dictionary,self.minWordSize,self.minSubwordSize,self.maxSubwordSize,s.find(subword),s.find(subword)+len(subword)))

    def incrementToken(self):
        if (not self.tokens.isEmpty()):
            assert self.current!=None
            token=self.tokens.removeFirst()
            AttributeSource.restoreState(self.current)
            self.termAtt.setEmpty().append(token.txt)
            self.offsetAttribute.setOffset(token.startOffset, token.endOffset)
            self.posIncAtt.setPositionIncrement(0)
            return True

        self.current=None

        if(self.input.incrementToken()):
            if self.termAtt.length()>=self.minWordSize:
                decompose()
                if not tokens.isEmpty():
                    self.current=AttributeSource.captureState()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def reset(self):
        super(CompoundTokenFilter,self).reset()
        self.tokens.clear()
        self.current=None

    class CompoundToken:
        def __init__(self,matchVersion,input,dictionary,DEFAULT_MIN_WORD_SIZE,DEFAULT_MIN_SUBWORD_SIZE,DEFAULT_MAX_SUBWORD_SIZE,offset,length):
            compoundTokenFilter=CompoundTokenFilter(matchVersion,input,dictionary,DEFAULT_MIN_WORD_SIZE,DEFAULT_MIN_SUBWORD_SIZE,DEFAULT_MAX_SUBWORD_SIZE)
            self.txt=compoundTokenFilter.termAtt.subSequence(offset, offset + length)

            startOff = compoundWordTokenFilterBase.this.offsetAtt.startOffset()
            endOff = compoundWordTokenFilterBase.this.offsetAtt.endOffset()

            if matchVersion.onOrAfter(Version.LUCENE_4_4) or endOff - startOff != compoundTokenFilter.termAtt.length():
                self.startOffset = startOff
                self.endOffset = endOff
            else:
                newStart = startOff + offset
                self.startOffset = newStart
                self.endOffset = newStart + length
```